# Gremlin/Python: run query as string

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I have the following code, and run as expected. But I need to use the "g" traversal object to manipulate the graph.

```
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g'))
g.V().drop().iterate()
g.addV('my-label').property('k', 'v').next()
print(g.V().toList())
```

Instead of the "g" object, I want to run string query to modify the graph, and the following doesn't work.

```
from gremlin_python.driver import client
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

ws_conn = DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin','g')
gremlin_conn = client.Client(ws_conn, "g")

query = "g.V().groupCount().by(label).unfold().project('label','count').by(keys).by(values)"
response = gremlin_conn.submit(query)

print(response)
```

Gives the following error:

```
(venv) sh-3.2$ python /Users/demo-prj/tests/tools/neptune/local.py
[v[4280]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/demo-prj/tests/tools/neptune/local.py", line 24, in <module>
    response = gremlin_conn.submit(query)
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/client.py", line 127, in submit
    return self.submitAsync(message, bindings=bindings, request_options=request_options).result()
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/client.py", line 148, in submitAsync
    return conn.write(message)
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 55, in write
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/connection.py", line 45, in connect
    self._transport.connect(self._url, self._headers)
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/tornado/transport.py", line 40, in connect
    self._ws = self._loop.run_sync(
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 576, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 547, in run
    result = func()
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gremlin_python/driver/tornado/transport.py", line 41, in <lambda>
    lambda: websocket.websocket_connect(url, compression_options=self._compression_options))
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1333, in websocket_connect
    conn = WebSocketClientConnection(request,
  File "/Users/demo-prj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 1122, in __init__
    scheme, sep, rest = request.url.partition(':')
AttributeError: 'DriverRemoteConnection' object has no attribute 'partition'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
from gremlin_python.driver import client
from tornado import httpclient

ws_url = 'ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'
ws_conn = httpclient.HTTPRequest(ws_url)
gremlin_conn = client.Client(ws_conn, "g")

query = "g.V().groupCount().by(label).unfold().project('label','count').by(keys).by(values)"
response = gremlin_conn.submit(query)

print(response)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you "need" to use string based queries?  TinkerPop seems to be leaning more towards what it refers to as bytecode queries (those embedded in your code).

Comment: It has to do with the previous design for some classes.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating?  I'm just curious if there is a gap that TinkerPop needs to address, or if this is related to some sort of tech-debt in your existing application/workload that is causing you to take this approach.

Comment: I'm running JanusGraph as my gremlin server and submit queries as strings quite a bit -- for the most part it's because I need to use JanusGraph-specific features that aren't supported by gremlinpython.